# How to set up a bridge with "bridge_ports none" on Debian Stretch in /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: debian, network-interface, bridge

When I have configured `br0` in `/etc/network/interfaces` with

```
iface br0 inet static
    address 10.0.10.1
    gateway 10.0.10.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 10.0.10.254
    bridge_ports none
```

and when I try to raise br0

```
$ ifup br0

Waiting for br0 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 32 seconds).
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
ifup: failed to bring up br0
```

`/var/log/syslog` says:

```
Could not generate persistent MAC address for br0: No such file or directory
```

Then in order to fix that, I found someone on the internet mentioning systemd's MACAdressPolicy in a more or less similar issue :

[udevd: "Could not generate persistent MAC address for $name: No such file or directory"](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3374#issuecomment-223753264)

I placed following content in `/etc/systemd/network/99-default.link`:

```
[Link]
NamePolicy=kernel database onboard slot path
MACAddressPolicy=none
```

But - still, when I

```
$ ifup br0

Waiting for br0 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 32 seconds).
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
ifup: failed to bring up br0
```

but `/var/log/syslog` contains no information about that event

Do you have a clue how a working configuration should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the default gateway to your own IP address doesn't make much sense thus isn't accepted:

```
$ sudo ifup -v br0

ifup: configuring interface br0=br0 (inet)
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/bridge

Waiting for br0 to get ready (MAXWAIT is 32 seconds).
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/vde2
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
/bin/ip addr add 10.0.10.1/255.255.255.0 broadcast 10.0.10.254    dev br0 label br0
/bin/ip link set dev br0   up
 /bin/ip route add default via 10.0.10.1  dev br0 onlink 
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
ifup: failed to bring up br0
```

Your broadcast setting is suspicious as well, the customary value would be 10.0.10.255, which you wouldn't even need to specify. Just use modern syntax:

```
iface br0 inet static
    address      10.0.10.1/24
    bridge_ports none
```